# How to set grid row getSelectionModel data in ext window

Tags: extjs

I am not bale to set row elected data in ext window, can you please give solution for this. my code is here..

```
var shiftWindow = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title: 'Edit Shift',
    resizable: false,
    id: 'shiftwindow',
    width: 465,
    //bodyPadding: 5,
    modal: true,
    store: shiftStorePlanner,

    items: {
        xtype: 'form',
        id: 'idFormShift',
        bodyPadding: 10,
        items: shiftViewModelPlannerData
    },
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Save',
        cls: 'planner-save-button',
        overCls: 'planner-save-button-over',
        handler: function() {
            var wi = this.up('.window')
            var form = Ext.getCmp('idFormShift');
            if (form.isValid()) {
                shiftTimemappingarray = [];
                getShiftTime();
                //this.up('.window').close();
            }
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Cancel',
        handler: function() {
            this.up('.window').close();
        }
    }]
});

    var host1 = Ext.getCmp('plannershifteditor');
    var selection = host1._shiftPlannerGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
    if (selection.length === 0) {

        return;
    }

    Ext.getCmp('shiftWindow').getForm().setValues(selection[0].data);
    shiftWindow.show();
     }
```

Comment: Please share your code in some fiddle it will help us for debugging and analyze issue.

Comment: Thanks for reply... Just wanted to tell you, my this code "Ext.getCmp('shiftWindow').getForm().setValues(selection[0].data);" line are not working..

Comment: I am using dynamic data Model with store and some other functionality with grid , so i am not able to run my code in fiddler. can you please check this line where i am getting issue..." Ext.getCmp('shiftWindow').getForm().setValues(selection[0].‌​data) ".please suggest me if i am using wrong properties for set value in window.

Comment: What extJS version are you using. Also your give some more light on your question.

Comment: we are using Ext version: "4.2.1"

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your ExtJS Version:

```
var selection = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
grid.getForm().loadRecord(selection[0]);
```

Later you can use `updateRecord()` to update the model with the form values.

More Infos:

- http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.form.Basic.html#method-loadRecord
- http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.form.Basic.html#method-updateRecord

ExtJS 5 and later supports also viewmodel binding. This will do the job automatically.